# I keep getting an error that say "cannot find symbol" when using a class from another file

Tags: java, quadtree

I am trying to create a Quadtree in a separate file from my Quadtree file.

```
Quadtree<String> blocky = new Quadtree<String>(rand.nextInt(5), new Quadtree.Boundry(0,0,rand.nextInt(750),rand.nextInt(750)));
```

However, I keep getting this error in the terminal.

```
error: an enclosing instance that contains Quadtree.Boundry is required
```

When I do it without the "Quadtree."  before Boundry, I get

```
error: cannot find symbol
```

Any suggestions for what I can do?

edit:

Here is part of my Quadtree class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

public class Quadtree
{

```
class Node{
    int x, y;
    E elem;
    Node(int x, int y, E elem)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.elem = elem;
    }

}

final int QT_NODE_CAPACITY = 64;
int level = 0;
ArrayList<Node> nodes;
public Quadtree NW = null;
public Quadtree NE = null;
public Quadtree SE = null;
public Quadtree SW = null;
Boundry bdry;

public Quadtree(int level, Boundry bdry)
{
    this.level = level;
    this.bdry = bdry;
    nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
}

class Boundry
{

    public int getXMin(){
        return xMin;
    }
    public int getXMax(){
        return xMax;
    }
    public int getYMin(){
        return yMin;
    }
    public int getYMax(){
        return yMax;
    }

    public Boundry(int xMin, int xMax, int yMin, int yMax)
    {

        super();
        this.xMin = xMin;
        this.xMax = xMax;
        this.yMin = yMin;
        this.yMax = yMax;

    }

    public boolean containsCoordinate(int x, int y)
    {
        return (x >= this.getXMin() && x <= this.getXMax() && y >= this.getYMin() && y <= this.getYMax());
    }

    int xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
}
```

Comment: Show us your Quadtree.

Answer (score 0):

`Boundry` must be declared as `static` to be instantiated without being scoped to a specific instance of `Quadtree`.